# Saving model to the server using Backbone and Node

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone / AJAX (and fresh to node, what my server is running on) and I'm trying to "save" my model to the user using the Save method from Backbone. I'm trying to implement a webchat for my university project. At the moment I want to send the provided username and password the user entered.

My server-side code:

```js
//Module user
exports.login = function(req, res) {
    console.log("login request");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

```js
//Main Server Script
app.post("/user/login", user.login);
```

My client-side code.

```js
login: function(self) {
    self.model.urlRoot = "/user/login";
    self.model.save({}, {
        success: function(model, response) {
                console.log('SUCCESS:');
                console.log(response);
            },
        error: function(model, response) {
                console.log('FAIL:');
                console.log(response);
            }
    });
}
```

The function is called by the view that holds the login button and gets the view as an argument. The view has a reference to its model.

On the server, I get the entered data as expected, but the response on the client gives me errors:

```
FAIL:
Object { 
    readyState: 4, 
    getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), 
    getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(),
    setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), 
    overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), 
    statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), 
    abort: .ajax/v.abort(), 
    state: .Deferred/d.state(), 
    always: .Deferred/d.always(), 
    then: .Deferred/d.then(), 
    // 11 weitere… 
}
```

I tried to figure it out by myself but I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server does not send anything back (or an OK string), the response can't be interpreted as valid JSON and jQuery then considers that the query failed.

In your user module, try

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
    console.log("login request");
    console.log(req.body);

    // send back an empty object
    res.json({}); 
};
```